# asp.net mvc custom model binder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My custom model binder which has been working perfectly has starting giving me errors

details below

> An item with the same key has already been added. Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key
>   has already been added.

Source Error:

> Line 31: { Line 32: string key = bindingContext.ModelName; Line 33:
>   var doc = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext) as
>   Document; Line 34: Line 35: // DoBasicValidation(bindingContext, doc);
>
> Source File: C:\Users\Bich Vu\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\PitchPortal\PitchPortal.Web\Binders\DocumentModelBinder.cs
>   Line: 33

Stack Trace:

> [ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
>   +51 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +7462172
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable1 source, Func2
>   keySelector, Func2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer1 comparer) +270
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(IEnumerable1 source, Func2
>   keySelector, IEqualityComparer1 comparer) +102
>   System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext.get_PropertyMetadata() +157
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
>   PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) +158
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +90
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model)
>   +50 System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +1048
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +280
>   PitchPortal.Web.Binders.documentModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) in
>   C:\Users\Bich Vu\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\PitchPortal\PitchPortal.Web\Binders\DocumentModelBinder.cs:33
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +257
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +109
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +314
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +105
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +39 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +7 System.Web.Mvc.<>c_DisplayClass8.b_4() +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_DisplayClass1.b_0() +21
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass81.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) +12 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult1.End() +59 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +44 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +7
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +8677678 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

any ideas guys? Thanks

Comment: Post some code of what you are doing in your binder.

Most likely the error is just what's in the stack trace - you are trying to add an item into a collection but that item (or an item with the same key) is already present in it.

This error often happens when you are copying collection, maybe when you iterate a collection in a for loop but are also trying to modify items in that same collection, etc..

Comment: public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
            string subject = request.Form.Get("doc.title");

          string key = bindingContext.ModelName;
            var doc = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext) as Document;

Comment: The faliure happens very early in the model binding code, from what I know asp.net model bindin works by getting values from querystring, post values etc and then adds then to some sort of dictionary, I am not trying to add anything to the collection, the built in model binding does that. The question is why would it be trying to add the same key

Comment: The code fails on the call to base.bindmode

Comment: ignore the first 2 HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request; string subject = request.Form.Get("doc.title");

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724601/asp-net-mvc-binding-specific-model-results-in-error-for-post-request/2724963#2724963), you probably got the same issue.

And please don't ask same question several times. You can just edit it.